# Live paint bucket tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, live-trace

I have a rather complex illustration I live traced and am wondering if it is possible to colour in quicker than colouring each individual petal, like a click and drag over the image without colouring in the outlines?

[image]

Comment: Ignore white when tracing, then simply put a color-filled object behind the black.

Comment: Ohh of course! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When tracing, tick the `Ignore white` option in the **Image Trace Panel** under the `Advanced` settings.

Then merely place a color-filled object behind your black trace.